# How to create view counter with PHP and MYSQL for every new day?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently writing my own CMS system in PHP.

All views of a post should be stored in the MySQL database every day.

Currently I have a view counter, which stores all post views of a post in the post table.

```
$article_id = $_GET['p_id'];

// article view counter
$view_query = "UPDATE articles SET article_views_count = article_views_count + 1 WHERE article_id = $article_id ";
$send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $view_query);
```

Now I want to change the whole thing that every day for each post a new entry is made in a separate table.

I've learned how to do it all, but my current SQL command adds a new entry to the table each time it's called, not counting for the whole day.

**The new SQL-Command:**

```
INSERT INTO days_views (`article_id`, `day_views_count`, `day`) VALUES (1, 1, CURDATE()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `day_views_count` = `day_views_count` + 1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `days_views` (
  `day_views_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day_views_count` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_german2_ci;

ALTER TABLE `days_views`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`day_views_id`);

ALTER TABLE `days_views`
  MODIFY `day_views_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

[My current test table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uixj.png)

How can I add one row every day for every post?

How can I count the views for the whole day?

Comment: Do you have a compound unique index on article_id - day columns? This is required for on duplicate key update extension to work.

Comment: I got that. I asked you about something else.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the DDL for your test table. As Shadow said, the index must include both the `days_views_ids` and `article_id` not just one or the other alone.

Comment: Please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections in your CMS. See https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table definition to use both `article_id` and `day` as the primary key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `days_views` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `day_views_count` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`, `day`),
  CONSTRAINT `article` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_german2_ci;
```

Then use an UPSERT statement to increment:

```sql
INSERT INTO days_views (`article_id`, `day`, `day_views_count`)
VALUES (<article_id>, CURDATE(), 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE day_views_count = day_views_count + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key needs to be a composite key of `day_views_id` and `article_id` NOT just `day_views_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE `days_views` ADD UNIQUE `CompKey` (`day_views_id`, `article_id`);
```

Once you add the unique index your existing logic will work. Do pay heed to the comments about SQL injection though too.

Answer (score -2):

It could be a good idea to think different.
I will try to explain:

### 1. How can I add one row every day for every post?

You could make an [insert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for every view hint saving the followings:

- day_views_id
- article_id
- day (must be DateTime or timestamp type, you will manipulate it better in PHP)

In this way, you **add one row every day for every post**.

### 2. How can I count the views for the whole day?

It's easy, you could make a [count();](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) of rows with a specific article_id, with a DateTime field = [NOW();](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp). This will return the total views for a specific article for a specific day.

It could be a good idea adding the [session id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) and store it for every insert to your table.

I hope I’ve been of help.